# Data from server not updated througn hg-bind in angular.js

Tags: angularjs

The data from server I want to display through `ng-bind` in angular.js. In the controller `scope.first_name` is updated. But it is not displayed in html. It shows error

> Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.14/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10 http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.14/%24rootScope/infdig?p0=10

Please tell me the solution for this issue. Through the below code only I tried.

```
$http.get('sample.php', config)
.success(function (data, status, headers, config)
{
      if (data.length >= 1) {
         $location.path("/inbox");
         $scope.first_name = data[0].firstname;
         console.log($scope.first_name);
      }
      else {
        alert("Invalid userid");
      }
 })
.error(function (data, status, headers, config)
{

});
```

Comment: The error is because of $digest cycle reached more than 10 times. You are changing the scope variable dynamically and each time digest cycle is called. Instead of assigning it to the $scope variable use some service module to return your data and assign it to the scope.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. But we need to pass some data to server to fetch information. In controller we can pass data like this var config = {
params: {
contact: contact
}
}  We can pass config as a parameter to http. But how i need to pass these values in service.

Comment: I would recommend this [tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_11) about services.

Comment: @Jeeva http://plnkr.co/edit/h3bD1w?p=preview Please go through the link and you can see that I am passing a string "uni" to the service function. Same way, you can pass your configuration parameters to that.

Comment: Hi Hurix. I tried with the help of the link what you sent. I am able to get data from server. But that is not updated through ng-bind. The same problem i faced in my previous code. Please help me to solve this.

Comment: app.factory('myService', function ($http) {
    var myService = {
        async: function (config) {
            var promise = $http.get('sample.php', config)
                    .success(function (data, status, headers, config)
                    {
                    })
                    .error(function (data, status, headers, config)
                    {

                    }).then(function (response) {
                return response.data;
            });
            return promise;
        }
    };
    return myService;
});

Comment: app.controller('formctrl', function ($scope, myService, $location) {

    $scope.submitData1 = function (contact, resultVarName)
    {
        var config = {
            params: {
                contact: contact
            }
        }
        myService.async(config).then(function (data) {
            if (data.length >= 1) {
                //$location.path("/inbox");
                $scope.first_name = data[0].firstname;
                console.log($scope.first_name);
            }
            else {
                alert("Invalid userid");
            }
        });
    };
});

Comment: The above two post contains code i have tried